# Is this how we use Interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, interface

Understanding interfaces in Java with example (checking what I learnt is correct)

Suppose we have an interface called `RemoteControl` that declares a method `turnOn()`:

```java
// Interface defining the RemoteControl contract
interface RemoteControl {
    void turnOn();
}
```

Now, we have two classes TV and AC, both of which implement the `RemoteControl` interface:

```java
// TV class implementing the RemoteControl interface
class TV implements RemoteControl {
    @Override
    public void turnOn() {
        System.out.println("TV is turned on");
    }
}

// AC class implementing the RemoteControl interface
class AC implements RemoteControl {
    @Override
    public void turnOn() {
        System.out.println("AC is turned on");
    }
}
```

Now, in the user code, we can interact with the TV and AC objects through the `RemoteControl` interface:

```java
public class UserCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoteControl tvRemote = new TV(); // Create a TV object using the RemoteControl interface reference
        RemoteControl acRemote = new AC(); // Create an AC object using the RemoteControl interface reference

        tvRemote.turnOn(); // Calls the turnOn() method on the TV object
        acRemote.turnOn(); // Calls the turnOn() method on the AC object
    }
}
```

In this example, the `UserCode` class represents the user code that interacts with the TV and AC objects. And here user code creates objects of TV and AC classes using the `RemoteControl` interface reference.

By using the `RemoteControl` reference, is this where we say like --> " *User actually uses an interface (remote control) rather than interacting directly with classes (T.V class)*".

So when we use this reference we are not actually instantiating T.V class but using and interface reference so that User can use it. And hence we achieve here total **Abstraction** ( if more functionalities were included ) by not interacting directly with T.V class but only interface.

And also we are able to make use of **Polymorphism**.
As a beginner learner i dont have much hands on Polymorphism yet but from code what i say is as a static **Polymorphism** when TV class and remote class would have again one same methods but with different parameters like ***turnOn(int channelNum)*** and same in **AC class** like ***turnOn(int increaseTemp)***, The compiler knows at compile time which implementation of the turnOn() method to call based on the reference type (RemoteControl).

Yeah and for **dynamic Polymorphism** there should be **inheritance** included and then methods **Overrinding** would make sense even more,here i have not provided much details just making sure my understanding is correct or not

Comment: Well a TV is not a remote control. A *TV remote* is a remote; a remote *for* a TV. So the classes should more accurately be called 'TVRemote' and 'ACRemote'. Maybe if you expanded the model a bit more, TVRemote would hold a reference to a TV - the TV that it's associated with. Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: @Michael just replace RemoteControl with RemoteControllable and its good. You are correct though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation at the end is incorrect. You do not achieve **TOTAL** abstraction the way you describe it.  You **ARE** instantiating a `TV` object and an `AC` object.  The polymorphism is **static polymorphism**, not dynamic polymorphism.  So when you call the functions they operate **directly on the instantiated class** with the efficiency as if it was regular method.

By implementing an interface in a class you are saying that your class behaves according to that interface in addition to anything else it does.  That means users can expect it to have certain features and behaviors without knowing subtleties of your class allowing for more abstraction and generalized usage.

I want to point out that your ultimate usage **IS** correct.

Comment: Your advice about `override` might apply to C++, but this is Java. `@Override` here is syntactic sugar, the only thing it will ever cause to be different in code is a build failure if you add it to a method which isn't overriding any method. Additionally, all Java methods are "virtual" in the sense that they will always dynamically dispatch the in-memory object for the class used when defining the object (working up the inheritance chain further if it was not overridden).

Comment: It just an Example. I did not provide whole model, it was only for understanding purpose. Obv for total abstraction it would need more functionalities, As a beginner learner wanted to check what i am learning is correct line or not. And As for Polymorphism yes its a static polymorphism, i did not specify much complicated example just as per my basic knowledge I said it as a Polymorphism i still dont have much hands on Polymorphism but with practise i will try to understant what you actually meant. And for Overriding methods, as i said i did not provide full functionalities it just simple eg.

Comment: override has the exact same effect in modern C++.  it causes a compiler error if you aren't overriding a virtual function from a base class.  I'll take it on assumption that it considers an interface implemented method to be an override, that actually seems like a useful thing for the same reason its useful in C++. I've removed that statement accordingly.  Your "everything is virtual" is a gross oversimplification that I'm not even going to get into.

Comment: The point is you operate directly on the instantiated objects, you said in your question that you weren't. Thats the key point I'm describing that you got wrong. Thats a key difference between the types of polymorphism.

Comment: @SouravKarjole yes we all understand and APPRECIATE that you kept the thing simple that you shared and asked about.  That is a core tenet of asking a good question here! I think its commendable that you asked the question and put together a minimal functional example for it.  As for the difference I'm getting at, you will need to understand the difference between 'extending' a class vs. 'implementing' an interface. Which are Java's way of saying "inheritance"/dynamic polymorphism or "contract composition"/static polymorphism. you are on a good path

Comment: @UpAndAdam i updated the explanation with more details. Can you check now ? and Thanks

Comment: its slightly better i would just edit above the original text, "So when we use this reference we are not actually instantiating T.V class but using and interface reference so that User can use it" to be "So when we use this reference we are utilizing the interface methods of the concrete target class such as `TV` as specified in the interface"

Comment: @UpAndAdam ohh mean that we are instantiating T.V class but using interface reference we are utilizing the interface methods of the concrete target class such as TV as specified in the interface??

Answer (score 0):

In general your understanding is correct: interface is the means of describing a contract of interaction of a particular implementation of the interface with other code. Interfaces allow you to write your code in more general way.

Comment: except its not correct because they are instantiating a tv object and an ac object.  Static polymorphism is occuring here not dynamic and not what they describe. Its just that they are both guarenteed to share the common interfaces of the remote control class.

Comment: Well, for dynamic polymorphism you should have kind of dependency injection here. It looks like the topic-starter has just started to use Java.

Comment: This isn't dynamic polymorphism. Inheratance is dynamic, interfaces are static.. its a fundamental difference. You are telling her she's right when she is wrong.

Comment: dependency injection has nothing to do with this